# Rake aborted after FATAL no pg_hba.conf entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

Trying to run my Rails 4.0.4 (Ruby 2.1.1) application on CentOS 6.5

Failing when I attempt to migrate:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "my_user", database "my_database_dev", SSL off
```

I am not sure how to tackle this one. On my mac setup all worked fine without having to touch the pg_hba.conf.

Any lead is welcome.

I have created `my_user` as follow:

`CREATE ROLE my_user WITH CREATEDB SUPERUSER LOGIN;`

And allowed my_user to access all database with 'trust' in the `pg_hba.conf`

### my `config/database.yml` contains

```
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_database_dev
  pool:     5
  username: my_user
  password:
  template: template0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `rake` is for some reason passing a bad **host**, as I assume **::1** is not the name of your server (it looks more like an IP mask of sorts from the Postgres config). (**Edit:** `::1` is IPv6 localhost, per Doon's comment below.)

Not sure offhand why the same code would work OK on your Mac, but I assume there's a `database.yml` involved in your `Rails` config? You may want to try specifying a `host` attribute in there (it can point to localhost if your server is local) and see if that helps.

i.e.

```
host: localhost
```

You'd also want to include one for the `port` if Postgres is not on the standard port for your Postgres install (**5432** with a default install).

Comment: updated my question with my database.yml, host is set to localhost and I am using the default port. thx for the lead, I will keep on investigating

Comment: ::1 is localhost in ipv6.

Comment: Ah, OK. I haven't had occasion to use ipv6 w/ Postgres yet. Good to know, thx.

Answer (score 0):

::1 is localhost in ipv6. Your PostgreSQL config doesn't have a config for v6. Try setting your server to 127.0.0.1 the ipv4 address of localhost.