# Connecting to Postgres 9.5 DB in rails results in FATAL no pg_hba.conf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to my RDS database via rails console but seem to be hitting the following issue:

> /gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "94.xx.xxx.xx", user "DATABASE_NAME", database USERNAME, SSL off (PG::ConnectionBad)

I've come across a handful of similar questions surrounding this such as:

- [connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)
- [Rake aborted after FATAL no pg_hba.conf entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747431/rake-aborted-after-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry/23748776#23748776)
- [no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

My `pg_hba.conf` currently looks like:

```
  # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
local   all             all                                     md5
hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust
host  <DB_NAME> <USERNAME>     94.XXX.XXX.XXX/32       trust
```

I've tried also tried adding the following line to my `pg_hba.conf` stopped and started the postgres service and still i'm still running into the same issue.

`hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust`

I also have the following in my `postgresql.conf`

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I've ran out of ideas on what I could be missing

Comment: Can you access to your database with the same credentials directly with psql?

Comment: you do have real user name and db name in pg_hba.conf, right? I can't tell if you put <DB_NAME> in the file or if you're just hiding the real value from us! The values in pg_hba.conf should match the values in your rails config/database.yml file.